# JAAS Error: Login failed

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jaas

i'm building some restful webservices and try to secure them by using JAAS.

but i get the following error:

```
 javax.servlet.ServletException: Login failed
```

I created a realm with the following attributes:

```
JAAS-Context: jdbcDigestRealm
DIGEST-Algorithm: SHA-512
Encoding: Hex
password encryption: none
```

I try to log in by using HttpServletRequest:

```
request.login(email, password); //email = test@test.tld, password=<SHA512HEX('testPasswprd')>
```

Here is the StackTrace:

```
WARNING:   WEB9102: Web Login Failed: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: null
SEVERE:   javax.servlet.ServletException: Login failed
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.doLogin(AuthenticatorBase.java:959)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.login(AuthenticatorBase.java:939)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.login(Request.java:2245)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.login(Request.java:2224)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.login(RequestFacade.java:1113)
```

Do you have some ideas?

---

EDIT:

Sometimes I get a NullPointerException at

```
request.login(email, password); //both variables and request are set.


WARNING:   StandardWrapperValve[de.AuthTest.core.ApplicationConfig]: Servlet.service() for servlet de.AuthTest.core.ApplicationConfig threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.login(Request.java:2229)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.login(Request.java:2224)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.login(RequestFacade.java:1113)
```

Comment: Does anyone have an idea? What could it be?

Comment: Have you configured JAAS on Glassfish server?

Comment: I created a jdbcrealm via the glassfish webconsole and added it to my glassfish-web.xml. Is there more to configure for glassfish?

Comment: I have worked on WebSphere but not Glassfish. It is a two step process which involves configuring the realms and modifying the deployment descriptor. Please see this link: http://developinjava.com/articles/securing-a-web-application-on-glassfish-using-jaas/

Comment: thanks for you reply. I worked with a tutorial which is very similiar but i want to do it with digest authentication. i think that i made something wrong there. Do you know the differences of implementing basic and digest authentication? maybe it helps me.

Answer (score 1):

[This tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncbx.html) was tested in Glassfish 4.0 with Java EE 7 application:

1. Expand the Security node.
2. Expand the Realms node.
3. Select the File node.
4. On the Edit Realm page, click Manage Users.
5. On the File Users page, click New.
6. In the User ID field, type a User ID.
7. In the Group List field, type TutorialUser.
8. In the New Password and Confirm New Password fields, type a password.
9. Click OK.

Then set up Default Principal to Role Mapping on the GlassFish Server:

1. From the Administration Console, expand the Configurations node, then expand the server-config node.
2. Select the Security node.
3. Select the Default Principal to Role Mapping Enabled check box.
4. Click Save